# Argument Error when trying Post request to localhost server using Postman

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, postman

I am trying to set up my database for a project right now but am running into a issue preventing me from moving forward. I set up the below controller to create new posts using Rails.

```
def create
        new_post = Post.create!(post_params)
        render json: new_post, status: :created
    end

def post_params
        params.permit(:post_body, :user_id, :likes, :sports_id)
    end
```

I set up initial seed data and when I ran db:seed I got no errors and it displayed the complete message I set up in the file. When I run a GET request in Postman I get an empty array showing the seed data never came through. If I try to use Postman to do a POST request I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VfnB.png)

Does anyone have any idea on whats going on?

I tried manually entering a test post through the terminal and still got an error. I have looked at previous projects that i've done that have similar setups with things like Posts, but I don't recall running into this error.

Answer (score 0):

@Hi M_Shkreli21,

To know how it failed, you should use debug to check

```
def create
   new_post = Post.new(post_params)
   # put byebug or debugger
   if new_post.save
     render json: new_post, status: :created
   else
     render json: "#{new_post.errors.full_message}", status: unprocessable_entity
   end
end
```

After that, you use postman to request

example: My console
[image]

You can check `params`, `post_params`, `new_post.errors.full_message` ...

=> Finaly, You can fix it